# Battling type parameter order and enable_if specifications in function templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, function-templates

Consider:

```
template <typename InputIt, typename T = typename std::remove_const<typename InputIt::value_type>::type>
  std::vector<T> WorkOnIt( InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    std::vector<T> result(first, last);
    ...fiddle with result...
    return result;
}
...
std::set<OneType> goods;
std::vector<OneType> cooked;
...
cooked = WorkOnIt( goods.begin(), goods.end());
```

This compiles and works but I'm not happy with it even though the call site is clean. If I want to explicitly specify `T`, I can't just `WorkOnIt<CookedType>` because I'd have to specify `InputIt` in front of that. That's ugly since that type is manifest in the argument list. And besides I just want the input iterators to cough up something that is convertible to `T`. Say like this:

```
std::set<SourceType> goods;
std::vector<CookedType> cooked;
...
cooked = WorkOnIt<CookedType>( goods.begin(), goods.end());
```

There must be some `enable_if` incantation that does what I want but I can't figure it out. (BTW, I'm stuck on C++17.)

Comment: [Reordering C++ template type parameters for usability purposes, and type deduction from the future](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230609-00/?p=108318)

Comment: @RaymondChen wow a ready made article! Can you comment on the user7860670 answer below? I've never seen overloads based on the ordering of template parameters and feel uneasy.

Comment: It does make me uneasy but I don't know why. Overall, though, it looks spiffy and a lot easier to read. There is a problem if Item == InputIt, and it should use `iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type` instead of just `InputIt::value_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using two overloads: one with deduced `Item` parameter and another with explicit.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Item, typename InputIt>
[[nodiscard]] ::std::vector<Item> WorkOnIt(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    ::std::cout << "explicit Item\n";
    ::std::vector<Item> result{first, last};
    //...fiddle with result...
    return result;
}

template <typename InputIt, typename Item = ::std::remove_const_t<typename InputIt::value_type>>
[[nodiscard]] ::std::vector<Item> WorkOnIt(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    ::std::cout << "implicit Item\n";
    return ::WorkOnIt<Item, InputIt>(first, last);
}

int main()
{
    ::std::set<::std::string> goods{};
    ::std::vector<::std::string> cooked{};
    cooked = ::WorkOnIt<::std::string>(goods.begin(), goods.end());
    cooked = ::WorkOnIt(goods.begin(), goods.end());
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/fb7sh54oz)

> explicit Item
> implicit Item
> explicit Item

If forward declaration of this function is not required then code can be simplified to utilize deduced return type and to eliminate deduced `Item` parameter completely:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename Item, typename InputIt>
[[nodiscard]] auto WorkOnIt(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    ::std::cout << "explicit Item\n";
    ::std::vector<Item> result{first, last};
    //...fiddle with result...
    return result;
}

template <typename InputIt>
[[nodiscard]] auto WorkOnIt(InputIt first, InputIt last)
{
    ::std::cout << "implicit Item\n";
    return ::WorkOnIt<::std::remove_const_t<typename InputIt::value_type>, InputIt>(first, last);
}

int main()
{
    ::std::set<::std::string> goods{};
    ::std::vector<::std::string> cooked{};
    cooked = ::WorkOnIt<::std::string>(goods.begin(), goods.end());
    cooked = ::WorkOnIt(goods.begin(), goods.end());
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/EzGWYYo46)

Comment: What's up with using `::std` ?

Comment: @JanSchultke Rule of thumb: if you want to access a name from global namespace then use `::` explicitly.

Comment: Says who? You're the only person I've ever seen write `::std` everywhere. Neither CppCoreGuidelines nor any C++ books I know recommend this style.

Comment: @JanSchultke That's a recommendation from my personal experience. I actually put a lot of efforts to make sure that names i use in my code are straightforward and unambiguous, to avoid shadowing and to avoid ADL. Usual textbook stuff like `string::string string;` causes a lot of trouble in large scale projects.

Comment: @user12002570 Note that name `std` is not reserved or anything. I don't see any reason for making an exception for it.

Comment: I don't see what you gain from disambiguating everything everywhere when only a small amount of names need disambiguation. People aren't exactly going around and defining `ns::std::has_unique_object_representations` all the time, so you're probably good to go without the `::std` on that one. If anything, you lose because you draw attention away from the places that need disambiguation. The noise is bad enough as a visual reader, but if I was blind and had to use a screen reader which screams "colon colon" at me a million times, that would be even worse. Consider accessibility.

Comment: @JanSchultke Indeed, "only a small amount of names need disambiguation", however i'd rather avoid ambiguity in advance rather than deal with consequences of messing with it later. Yes, i've actually dealt with them a couple of times and it was a horrible experience. Also simpler rules are easier to follow, check or enforce. Using `::` for global names is simpler than using `::` for global names except std, boost, etc. or using `::` for global names depending on context. *The noise is bad enough as a visual reader...* - 100% agree.

Comment: @user7860670 I've never seen overloads based on the ordering of template parameters before and feel uneasy. Is this a common technique?

Comment: @Mustang This is usual SFINAE-based overloads. Putting `Item` at the first position makes it non-deducible so this overload won't be selected unless first template parameter is explicitly provided. While second overload won't be selected when first template parameter is explicitly provided because substituting it fails.

Comment: Substitution succeeds if InputIt is an iterator whose iterated type is convertible to InputIt, and then you get an "ambiguous overload" error. (Also, use `iterator_traits` to avoid problems if the InputIt is a pointer.)